# Как преобразовать массив в лист

Tags: python, массивы, list

Есть массив:

```
a = array([[10],
           [12],
           [14]])
```

Как получить список:

```
a = [[10],[12],[14]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас array из numpy, то вот так:

```py
from numpy import array

a = array([[10],
           [12],
           [14]])
a = a.tolist()
```